# sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

For geometric series $6+ 3+ \frac{3}{2} + . . .,$ obtain the smallest value of $n$ if the difference between the sum of the first
$n + 4$ terms and the sum of first $n$ terms is less than $$\frac{45}{64}$$
The answer is $5$, but I am not sure how to find it

Comment: Write out all the information you know. Formula for each term in the sequence, formula for the sum of the first $N$ terms. Then try to piece it together.

Comment: I gt stuck when doing the calculation

Comment: Well, type it up so that we can check it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$a+aq + aq^2 + \cdots + aq^{n} = a(1 + q + \cdots + q^n) = a\cdot \frac{q^{n+1} - 1}{q-1}$$